# JavaScript, AngularJS: How do I know if element is larger than its container?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let’s say I have a title in h1 element (any element would do). Its content is dynamic (do not know length of the title). It is supposed to be displayed in one line. h1 is in a DIV (let’s call it a container) of limited size.

How do I know if element (h1) overflows its container (DIV)?

So that if it overflows I would apply a CSS class to deal with the situation. For example I would scroll hidden content of h1 into view.

- Width of the container is defined as relative to the screen size.

Example:

```css
#container {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 50px;
    // overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>a soft white or grey mineral consisting of hydrated calcium sulphate. It occurs chiefly in sedimentary deposits and is used to make plaster of Paris and fertilizers, and in the building industry.</h1>
</div>
```

Best solution would be if it could be used in: primary in `ngIf`, secondary in `ngClass` directives, but any of following technologies are also good: `Javascript`, `AngularJS`, `CSS`, `AngularJS directive`.

Comment: I don't understand,  so you want the entire content of h1 to be displayed with in container?

Comment: Eventually yes, but I do not want to change size of the container, so if content overflows I want to  conditionally apply a CSS class to scroll the content(h1). Problem is that I do not know how to make the “condition”.

Comment: You can do it with pure css, just give overflow: auto to the container. It will detect if the content inside overflows and add a scrollbar only if it overflows.

Comment: It is for a mobile application where container is already quite small. Scroll bar would obstruct view and it would be almost impossible to use it on small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution in `AngularJS directive`. It does not rely on parent element:

```
var myDirective = angular.module('myDirective', []);
myDirective.directive( 'myDirective' , ['$timeout' , function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope , element , attrs) {

            // Wait few milliseconds until element is re-rendered 
            // so that element properties reflect content size.
            $timeout( function(){
                if (element[0].scrollWidth > element[0].offsetWidth){
                    // overflow
                }
            }, 200); // $timeout
        } // link
    }; // return
}]); // myDirective
```

Usage example:

```
<h3 my-directive>Hello World!</h3>
```

*Note: Parent element must have restricted size otherwise it will adjust to the content and element will never overflow.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jquery you could check widths of the elements.

```
if ($('h1').scrollWidth >   $('#container').innerWidth()) {
//overflown
```

}

Comment: At the moment `jquery` is my least favorite, but let's see. Thank you for effort!

Comment: +1 for showing me direction. BTW: I think this condition is even better: `element.scrollWidth > element.offsetWidth`. It does not rely on parent element.